# IntelliJ - see all available application.yml properties

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Is there a way in IntelliJ to see all the available keys for a given property like `spring:`?  I just keep typing one letter and looking through the list, but that's pretty random.  Is there some hotkey that will show all the possible autocompletes that could be used in an Spring application properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a HotKey - it's `Ctrl+Space` (`^Space` in tech terms)